# Syncfusion Calendar is not showing the first time interval

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion, syncfusion-calendar

I'm using the [syncfusion_flutter_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar), and on the Day view I'm showing a time range 7am - 5pm. My problem is that the first time (**7:00AM**) is not showing, instead what I see is **7:30AM**.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
SfCalendar(
  //dataSource: MeetingDataSource(_getDataSource()),
  allowedViews: const [CalendarView.day],
  timeSlotViewSettings: const TimeSlotViewSettings(
    startHour: 7.0,
    endHour: 17.0,
    timeInterval: Duration(minutes: 30),
    timeFormat: 'h:mm a',
  ),
)
```

I've tried to reduce the `startHour` by 30 minutes, but the visual is not exactly what I want (there is one extra row on top), in addition users can create appointments starting at 6:30AM.

[image]

Any help how to show the first time, will be appreciated.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct support to achieve your requirement that shows the starting time in the view. However, you can achieve this with the help of the time [specialRegions](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_calendar/latest/calendar/SfCalendar/specialRegions.html) property in the SfCalendar. Here, we set the [startHour](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_calendar/latest/calendar/TimeSlotViewSettings/startHour.html) as 6 in [timeSlotViewSettings](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_calendar/latest/calendar/TimeSlotViewSettings-class.html) and add the time region from 6 to 7 as a special region, and disable the interaction in that special region with the help of enablePointerInteraction.

I have shared the screenshot and code snippet below for your reference. We hope it will help you to achieve your requirements.

[image]

Code snippet:

```dart
DateTime initialDate = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: SfCalendar(
          allowedViews: const [CalendarView.day],
          specialRegions: [
            TimeRegion(
              startTime: DateTime(
                  initialDate.year, initialDate.month, initialDate.day, 06, 00),
              endTime: DateTime(
                  initialDate.year, initialDate.month, initialDate.day, 07, 00),
              recurrenceRule: 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1',
              enablePointerInteraction: false,
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
            )
          ],
          timeSlotViewSettings: const TimeSlotViewSettings(
            startHour: 6.0,
            endHour: 17.0,
            timeInterval: Duration(minutes: 30),
            timeFormat: 'h:mm ',
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
```